# How to add a Seperator in Pyro CMS Navigation

Tags: php, html, pyro

I would like to add a pipe "  |  " between each `li` item in PyroCMS Navigation

in the HTML template View we use

**code**

```
{{ navigation:links group="main_nav" }}
```

which outputs

**output**

```
#li><a href='#'>home</a></li>
#li><a href='#'>contact</a></li>
```

What I would like to do is have the pipe after the link

**output**

```
#li><a href='#'>home</a> | </li>
#li><a href='#'>contact</a> | </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the Pyro dcumentation,

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/modules-and-tags/tag-reference/navigation

Down at the bottom there is Advanced Options.
looks like i can use the attribv

```
 separator="|" 

{{ navigation:links group="main_nav"  separator="|"  }}
```